# How to remove border on layout

Tags: android, xml

Hi i would like to do this: 
[image]

And my solution

this set corner for linearlayout:
**drawable/draw_arc_corner_shape**

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"   >

<solid
    android:color="@color/bg_trip_tab_view" >
</solid>

<!--<stroke-->
    <!--android:width="0dp"-->
    <!--android:color="@color/bg_trip_tab_view" >-->
<!--</stroke>-->

<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"    >
</padding>

<corners
    android:radius="11dp"   >
</corners>
```

This part dwaw circle: 
**drawable/draw_circle_shape**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@color/bg_my_trip_tab_view" />
    <size
      android:height="10dp"
      android:width="10dp" />
</shape>
```

this draw dash line: **drawable/draw_dash_line_shape**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line" >
    <stroke
      android:dashGap="3dp"
      android:dashWidth="2dp"
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@color/bg_my_trip_tab_view" />
 </shape>
```

and here create view (separator) with circle (semicircle) on start and end and dash line between: **layout/separator**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<View
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_circle_shape"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_dash_line_shape"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_circle_shape"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here i use it: **layout/main_screen**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/bg_my_trip_tab_view"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/draw_arc_corner_shape"
    >
    <include
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/separator"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my result:
[image]

And my question: 
How can I remove border with shadow? And How can I do it better?

Comment: Possible solution: I can use image 9-path ... but i don't want ..

Comment: try to add android:stateListAnimator="@null" in your main_screen Linear layout

Comment: Hey, I tested your layout and didn't really get any shadows in both API 19 and API 24...

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting border shadow in Android Studio xml design view. On real device no shadow showing.

Comment: Your linear layout have some parent like card view?

Comment: I testing it on real device and there is shadows

Comment: u are using any parent of linear layout like cardview etc. That can have shadow.